# What are the main differences between Modern Warfare 3 and Modern Warfare 2/Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Besides updated plot and new features, were any actual changes made to the game engine or the graphics, etc.? It seems to me as though they are basically all the same.

Answer (score 2):

The engine in all three of these games is essentially the same. In Black Ops, you can dolphin dive and your grenades can't be thrown as far. Besides that the engine remained unchanged between MW2 and MW3.